# TeamCity Error: "cannot start build runner; NUnit runner failure"

Tags: c#, nunit, teamcity, integration-testing

---

**Cannot start build runner (1)**

Failed to start reason No assemblies were found.

**Uncategorized problem (1)**

Build failure reason NUnit runner failure

---

After building all of the projects and running a NUnit TestFixture in TeamCity I received the error "cannot start build runner; NUnit runner failure." All of the tests run, however at the end of the process the error was thrown. I looked up similar stack overflow questions, but I am unable to make any connections.

1. Why am I getting this error?
2. How might I go about fixing it?

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved:

1. An outdated project in the solution was removed. TeamCity was trying to run test for the project after it was removed which caused the error of not being able to find the assemblies.
2. The project was originally removed because it wasn't building, therefore I am refactoring the project and re-adding it to the solution.

Comment: Is there a way to fix a problem without re-adding projects?